# I'd like to be able to sort my favorite questions in my Network Profile by Site

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, network-profile, favorites-tab

I have an ever-growing list of "favorite" questions from different SE sites. Because I often forget which site I saved a specific question from, I go to my Network Profile, where I can find the whole list.

The current tabs for sort order are Votes, Recent, Newest and Added. It always defaults to Votes, which I don't find useful, as that's not a criteria by which I choose, or remember, my favorite questions. Recent and Newest are somewhat confusing. In addition, those three are subject to change on a daily basis due to activity. Added is self-explanatory, but not necessarily the most expedient way to search through a long list.

Since the originating site is already identified on each question, I'd appreciate the option to sort them that way, with a new tab labeled Site.

Comment: Hey Sue, would you mind if I grab this (interesting!) 'question' to suggest some edits? Would be great if "Le Patron", by coincidence, would get involved in the approval of such suggestions, no? I know, I don't really "have to" ask such permission according to the SE rules of the game. But we (people from my country) have a "reputation" (oeps!) in the 'real world' that we are (way too) polite. Hence my comment. Oeps: it's a "question", at risk for being flagged for removal. If that happens, I'll consider that as an implicit approval ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I hold manners in high regard, and don't think there's such a thing as too polite!  I do a lot of editing, always trying to add/subtract something to make things easier for future readers, and would very much appreciate you doing the same with this or any of my other questions.

Comment: Hm, interesting, looks like we are similar! Merci Beaucoup (oeps, I MUST speak English on SE ... Really?). Anyway, to the point. One of "my" criteria for picking questions to suggest an edit for, is to just look at the TITLE as it shows up on the right within "related" or "links". There is always (repeat always) at least 1 that makes me think "hm, just reading the title there I can impossibly predict what the content of the question is going to be. That's the one I go digging into" ... But THIS question is a variation of that: it is just not a question, it's a "statement" or "expression", no?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Yes, this is a statement rather than a question. I frequently edit titles to help them look more like questions, and I try to make my own requests in question-form. In this case, I couldn't figure out how to do that without making it longer than it already was! You'll find more of these types of titles on Meta than other sites, and many seem to be acceptable as long as they're clear. Did you know there's a [French SE site](http://french.stackexchange.com)? It might be a fun place for you!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. FYI: at this time I am not allowed to "suggest edits" (can you tell what happened?). And today I dared to ask a special question. I'd be curious to know your feedback about it whenever you have time for it. Also, thanks for the French SE, I signed up right away. And I did a special search ... http://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=mon+patron ... You must get it, right?